# La consulta sólo me devuelve la primer fila en vez de todas

Tags: php, sql

Código:

```php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tickets";

        if(isset($_POST['accion']) AND $_POST['accion']='buscador')
        {
            $palabra = cleanVar($_POST['palabra']);
            $sql .= " WHERE nombre LIKE '%".$palabra."%' OR telefono LIKE '%".$palabra."%' OR email LIKE '%".$palabra."%' OR marca LIKE '%".$palabra."%' OR modelo LIKE '%".$palabra."%' OR imei LIKE '%".$palabra."%'";
        }
        $res = $db->query($sql) or die("error: ".$sql);
        if($res->num_rows > 0)
        {
            while($row = $res->fetch_assoc())
            {
                $nombre = $row['nombre'];
                $marca = $row['marca'];
                $modelo = $row['modelo'];
                $estado = $row['estado'];
                if($estado == 1)
                {
                    $estado_nombre = "PENDIENTE";
                }elseif($estado == 2)
                {
                    $estado_nombre = "ACEPTADO";
                }elseif($estado == 3)
                {
                    $estado_nombre = "DENEGADO";
                }elseif($estado == 4)
                {
                    $estado_nombre = "SE REQUIERE MAS INFORMACIÓN";
                }
                $estadosql="SELECT estado FROM tickets_historial WHERE ticket = '".$row['ticket']."'";
                    $res=$db->query($estadosql) or die ("error: ".$estadosql);
                    $r = $res->fetch_assoc();
                    $rowcount = $res->num_rows;
                    if ($rowcount == 0){
                        $info_estado = 1;
                    } else{
                    $estado = $r['estado'];
                    }
                ?>
                 <tr>
                    <td><?= $row['id'] ?></td>
                    <td><?= $row['ticket'] ?></td>
                    <td><?= date("d/m/Y", strtotime($row['fecha_creacion'])) ?></td>
                    <td><?= $marca ?></td>
                    <td><?= $modelo ?></td>
                    <td><?= $nombre ?></td>
                    <td><?= $estado_nombre ?></td>
                    <td><?= $info[$info_estado] ?></td>
                    <td><a href="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>?accion=ver_ticket&ticket=<?= $row['ticket'] ?>"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i></a></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
```

No me funciona la consulta `$estadosql`, es decir funciona pero sin esa consulta me devuelve todos los valores de la tabla `tickets`. Al poner esa consulta, sólo me devuelve 1 fila en vez de todas y no entiendo por qué.

Teóricamente está dentro de un bucle con lo cual tiene que hacer la consulta cada vez que pasa por el bucle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) // <-- $res
{
  // ...
  $estadosql="SELECT estado FROM tickets_historial WHERE ticket = '".$row['ticket']."'";
  $res=$db->query($estadosql) or die ("error: ".$estadosql); // <-- $res again
```

Fíjate que en la query anidada estás almacenando el resultado en `$res`, que es la variable que estás usando para almacenar el resultado de la primera consulta.

Considera la posibilidad de usar una variable diferente para la segunda consulta.